# How to read do not disturb using applescript?

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, macos-monterey, do-not-disturb

I am trying to read status of do not disturb or dnd using applescript.

For some reason, it always return "1" no matter what if the dnd is on or off.

```
do shell script "defaults -currentHost read ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.notificationcenterui doNotDisturb"
```

Stack
Editor: Script Editor to create and run the script
OS: macOS Monterey

Comment: FYI, I've also tried without the full path to com.apple.notificationcenterui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution for Monterey

```
#!/bin/bash
defaults read com.apple.controlcenter "NSStatusItem Visible FocusModes"
```

It returns `1` if "Do Not Disturb" is enabled, `0` otherwise.

Comment: Hmm, I'm on Monterey. Above command always returns 0, but other solutions posted here don't work either. The system keyboard binding  works thou.

Comment: It works perfectly for me, perhaps it depends on some specific setting on your machine?

Comment: Works great but how can add a observer to the DND to know if the DND change is state?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind reading it via the UI on Mac OS Monterey

```
log getDNDStatus()

on getDNDStatus()
    set currentState to 1
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "ControlCenter"
        click of menu bar item "Control Center" of menu bar 1
        if exists (first checkbox of front window whose title is "Focus") then set currentState to 0
    end tell
    tell application "System Events" to key code 53 -- Escape to close the control center popup
    currentState
end getDNDStatus
```

Comment: Thank you it works, is there a way to read the value without opening control center (from visual point of view)?

Comment: I think there's a way to do that by comparing the plist file that stores the configuration, before and after you change a setting via UI. It's not as clear cut as far as I remember and unfortunately, I couldn't find notes on that so you'll need to Google it, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

On my Catalina your plain Apple-script works fine:

```
set DNDStatus to (do shell script "defaults -currentHost read com.apple.notificationcenterui  doNotDisturb") as integer as boolean
```

Here is AppleScript Objective-C solution:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set defaults to current application's NSUserDefaults's alloc()'s initWithSuiteName:"com.apple.notificationcenterui"
set DNDStatus to (defaults's valueForKey:"doNotDisturb") as boolean
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, seems like both approaches doesn't work in monterey. I believe Apple might have changed something significantly on notifications side perhaps something to do with Focus mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shell script too:

```
#!/bin/bash
DNDStatus=$(defaults -currentHost read com.apple.notificationcenterui  doNotDisturb)
echo $DNDStatus
```

Comment: it always returns "0" on monterey